# Create Image Slider of give type? Android

Tags: android

I want to create a image slider in which focussed image appear little bigger than other in that slider.

Comment: show effort, this isn't a "plz giff codez or riot" type of site.

Comment: i just Add ImageView in HorizontalScrollBar.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Android Gallery View for this

Comment: by this i can add multiple image but how can i increase the size of image on centre of screen..?

Comment: You need to customize gallery